# git-svn : rebase fails multiple times then works

Tags: git-svn

We are rolling out git on our clients to interact with a central SVN repository. On most work stations it works fine, but we have one work station where the person has to run git svn rebase 3-4 times before it completes. Each time there is no error, but random files are marks as modified or new. The files seem to be a commit that was pulled down from the central svn repository but not completed. Rerunning git svn rebase again a few times clears this up. The computer is top of the line with plenty of hard drive space and 16 gigs ram. Has anyone else ran into issues like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue that was solved by upgrading to git 1.8.

[Why does "git rebase" leave opposite sets of modifications in the stage and the working copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183534/why-does-git-rebase-leave-opposite-sets-of-modifications-in-the-stage-and-the)

Maybe you should try that.